# Colorbox video doesn't play

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

We want to use Colorbox for some of the Youtube videos on our site.
When you click on the "Learn More" link the Colorbox pop-up comes up, but the video is missing, there is just a white box.

cresinsurance.com/product-finder-tool/non-mandatory-individual-real-estate/

On the above page, if you scroll down to the "Policy Details" section, you'll see a play button with the text "Learn More". this is supposed to be a colorbox popup that will play a Youtube video.

Not sure what we're missing.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

never mind... there was another plugin that was interfering with the Colorbox script. All fixed and working